# working with the refreshApex feature in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Okay, i'm looking to see if I can get some help in understanding the documentation as laid out here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/reference_salesforce_modules

I want to refresh a component after a record CRUD operation, the form is being populated from a call to an apex method. The data from this method (called with the @wire service) is then passed into a js function that splits the data into complete and incomplete todo items. Wire service call is:

```
  @wire(getTodos, {
    searchKey: '$searchString'
  })
  sendForSplitting({
    error,
    data
  }) {
    if (error) {
      this.error = error;
    } else if (data) {
      this.splitTodos(data);
    }
  }
```

In an event handler i want to trigger an update to this dataset, the documentation above seems to reference that I can refresh the apex on a wired method. From that doc:

> To refresh a wired method, you must pass the argument the wired method receives (which is the wired value).

To date, I have tried both:

```
  handleCreate() {
    return refreshApex(getTodos, {
      searchKey: '$searchString'
    });
  }
```

and

```
  handleCreate() {
    return refreshApex(this.sendForSplitting({
      error,
      data
    }));
  }
```

Both of which throw errors - refresh failed because configuration is not available. How can I make this work? I want to ensure the lists update upon user interaction without having to resort to a manual refresh of the page...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Going by the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex), it seems you will need to create an additional property and utilize that in your wired function.

> To refresh a wired method, pass the argument the wired method receives (which is the wired value) to `refreshApex()`. In this sample code, the wired method is `wiredGetActivityHistory(value)`. Hold on to the value provisioned by the wire service and pass it to `refreshApex()`.

You will need to declare another variable, say `mySendForSplitting` and then utilize that in your `sendForSplitting`, something as:

```
sendForSplitting({error,data}) {
    this.mySendForSplitting = data;
    // rest of the code
}
```

And then use `refreshApex()` as below:

```
refreshApex(this.mySendForSplitting);
```

You can find an [example on the lwc-recipe](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsDeleteRecord/ldsDeleteRecord.js) as well.

Comment: thanks Jayant! that additional prop was the bit that i'd missed..

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue and the solution was to put `refreshApex` inside `.then()` method after successfully calling the server.

Here is the working example:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import findSomething from '@salesforce/apex/ApexController.findMethod';
import changeSomething from '@salesforce/apex/ApexController.changeMethod';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';

findSomething
changeSomething
@track paramForChangeOne
@track paramForChangeTwo

@wire(findSomething, { paramOne: '$paramOne', paramTwo: '$paramTwo' }) findSomething;

callFromHtml(){
        changeSomething({paramForChangeOne: this.paramForChangeOne, paramForChangeTwo: this.paramForChangeTwo})
        .then(result => {
            if(result){
                this.showNotification('success', 'Success Message', '');
            }
            // refreshing table data using refresh apex(HERE NEEDS TO BE SET)
            refreshApex(this.findSomething);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```