# lwc wired variable in refreshApex throws "resolved configuration is not available"

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, configuration, wire, refreshapex

I have worked myself through several topics here on StackExchange already, finding this one to be the most helpful:

[working with the refreshApex feature in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251259/working-with-the-refreshapex-feature-in-lwc)

However, the proposed solution does not work for me: Neither with a separate wire function nor with giving the result to a separate variable and using that one to refresh the page am I able to trigger a Refresh.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getDummy from "@salesforce/apex/msMCWF_PreInitiationCmpController.getDummyData"; 
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';


export default class McwfPreInit extends LightningElement {
@track trackedSteps;
@track selectedStep;
@track noStepSelected = true;
@track loaded;
dataInCache;

@wire(getDummy) 
getSteps(result){
   this.dataInCache = result;
    var arr = [];
    if(result.data){
        arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data));
        arr.forEach(function(item){
            item.showAction = getShowAction(item);
            item.isDone = getIsDone(item);
        });
        this.loaded = true;
    }else if(result.error){
        console.log('oof');
    }
    this.trackedSteps = arr;

    function getShowAction(step){
        return step.bg !== 'green' && step.hasAction;
    }

    function getIsDone(step){
        return step.bg === 'green';
    }
}

get loaded(){
    return !!this.trackedSteps;
}

renderedCallback(){
    this.template.addEventListener('refreshsteps', this.refresh);
}

refresh(){
    console.log('event received');
    this.loaded = false;
    this.trackedSteps = {};
    return refreshApex(this.dataInCache);
}

changeSteps(event){
    this.trackedSteps = event.detail.steps;
    this.selectedStep = event.detail.target;
    this.noStepSelected = false;
}
```

}

This is the entirety of my JS For for now. As you can see, I am setting `dataInCache` to the result of my wired callout. This is also what was advised in the aforementioned thread. However I am still unable to get this to work as I am still getting this error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Refresh failed because resolved configuration is not available.
at Object.e.refresh [as refreshApex] (lds.js:2)
at Object.refresh (mcwfPreInit.js:4)
at DocumentFragment.r (aura_prod.js:27)
at n (aura_prod.js:1)
at aura_prod.js:1
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at u (aura_prod.js:1)
at HTMLElement.nt (aura_prod.js:1)
at HTMLElement.He.e.$$lwcEventWrapper$$ (aura_prod.js:1)
at u.dispatchEvent (aura_prod.js:3)
```

I have also tried to call the refresh directly from a Button on the parent component itself, but that in itself triggered a TypeError: t[Yn] is not a function error. Something I have yet to understand completely.

What do I need to do to finally be able to refresh my variable via a button on a child component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**
It is because the scope of `refresh` method is not same as `McwfPreInit` when the event is fired. You need to use arrow function so that it will not have its own scope and the scope will always be same as `McwfPreInit` when event is fired.

```
refresh = () => {
    console.log('event received');
    this.loaded = false;
    this.trackedSteps = {};
    return refreshApex(this.dataInCache);
}
```

**Option 2:**
Instead of above confusion, you can just declare the event listener in the declaration of child component in HTML `onrefreshsteps={refresh}`

Comment: Implementing both proper propagation and using the fat arrow notation seem to have done the trick, there's a few other things I need to get working to finally have the refresh do what it's supposed to, but that's for another time. Thank you!